# Converting string containing multidimensional array keys and values PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, stdclass, recursive-backtracking

I use TPP `API` for check domain availability and domain register but i receive response in `string`.

1. Get Session, return string`OK: t73484678463765`
2. Domain check, return string `woohoo123.nz: OK: Minimum=1&Maximum=2`
3. In other case, return string `woohoo123.nz: ERR: 102, This is message`

When It return `OK` it has `&` in child but when `ERR` that time it has `,`

I want convert return `string` into `array`

such as input `woohoo123.nz: OK: Minimum=1&Maximum=2` and output following `array`

```
 [
     'woohoo123.nz' => [
         'OK' => [
             'Minimum' => 1,
             'Maximum' => 2,
         ]
     ]
 ]
```

input `woohoo123.nz: ERR: 102, This is message` and output following `array`

```
 [
     'woohoo123.nz' => [
         'ERR' => [
             'code' => 102,
             'message' => 'This is message',
         ]
     ]
 ]
```

I like more to reuse code, I prefer `recursive` and `callback` but not sure in this case.

Comment: I am unsure of what you want.  Can you give some more examples of possible string inputs and the `array`/`stdClass` output you desire?

Comment: I want to convert those strings into array. string includes `:`, `&` and `,` and convert into multidimensional array @HurricaneDevelopment

Comment: I have  rewritten the function.  It is pretty much only for this specific case.  Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for.  It works for your examples, but will only continue to work if the input strings follow that format strictly.

```
    function stringToArray($inputStr) {
    $array = [];

    $topComponents = explode(': ',$inputStr);
    $parametersStr = $topComponents[count($topComponents) -1];
    if (strpos($parametersStr,'&') !== FALSE) {
        $tmpArr = explode('&',$parametersStr);
        foreach ($tmpArr as $val) {
            $comp = explode('=',$val);
            $array[$comp[0]] = $comp[1];
        }
    } else if ($topComponents[count($topComponents) - 2] === "ERR") {
        $tmpArray = explode('ERR: ',$parametersStr);
        $tmpArray = explode(', ',$tmpArray[0]);
        $array = [
            "code" => intval($tmpArray[0]),
            "message" => $tmpArray[1]
        ];
    } else {
        $array = $parametersStr;
    }

    for ($i=count($topComponents) -2; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $newArray = [];
        $newArray[$topComponents[$i]] = $array;
        $array = $newArray;
    }

    return $array;
}

print_r(stringToArray("OK: t73484678463765"));
```

Comment: This is what I want. Thanks for your time!